# Interact with ListView Items

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application I have a ListView with custom items which looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minWidth="60dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:max="100" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want that the TextView has allways the progress of the SeekBar but I don't know how to interact with the ListViewItems. Of course I know that I have to create an `OnSeekBarChangeListener` and call something like `txt.setText("" + bar.getProgress());` but where should I create the Listeners and how am I sure that the right TextView is selected because all Items have the same Layout with same LayoutIDs. Here is a excerpt from my custom adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View row = convertView;
    Holder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.bar = (SeekBar) row.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        holder.txt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
    }

    Person p = data.get(position);

    holder.bar.setProgress(0);
    holder.txt.setText(p.getFullName());

    return row;
}

private static class Holder
{
    SeekBar bar;
    TextView txt;
}
```

Comment: Try something like this:

    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) row.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setYourListenersHere(yourListener);
    holder.bar = seekBar;

Comment: But then it can come to the problem that I touch the `SeekBar` from Item1 but the holder is set to Item3 and than the `TextView` from Item3 will change.

Comment: it should not happen, just give it a try. hope this helps :)

Comment: `it should not happen` even if I make `holder` global? I have to because (of course) holder in not known in `onProgressChanged`.

Comment: make it `final`, and you'll be able to access it in `onProgressChanged`

Comment: ^ don't make holder final, keep a similar approach with `TextView` and make that `final`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new Holder();

    final TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    holder.txt = textView;

    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) row.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        // Overridden methods
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // textView will be accessible here since its final 
            // and also in other overridden methods
        }
    });
    holder.bar = seekBar;

    row.setTag(holder);
}
```

Hope this helps :)